# Is there a Google Apps Script I can run to import multiple named ranges from the same source file?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to import multiple named ranges from a single tab of the source sheet. The current code is only able to import a single named range at once:

```
var sourceSpreadsheetID = "1234";
var sourceWorksheetName = "Export";
var targetSpreadsheetID = "5678";
var targetWorksheetName = "Import";

function importData() {
var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetID);
var thisWorksheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceWorksheetName);
var thisData = thisWorksheet.getDataRange();  //with your named range.
var thisData = thisSpreadsheet.getRangeByName("NamedRange1");

var toSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetID);
var toWorksheet = toSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetWorksheetName);
var toRange = toWorksheet.getRange(1, 1, thisData.getNumRows(), thisData.getNumColumns())
toRange.setValues(thisData.getValues());
}
```

Please assist me in getting the code to import multiple ranges from the same source sheet and tab.

I tried creating different scripts, each with the respective named range under the same project. However, I am getting some blank columns when I run the scripts.

Comment: Use `.getNamedRanges()` and loop through the ranges

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please help me by showing me how to do that?